# Function not toggling on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm writing a web page that has a from field that allows a user to select a gallery to associate an image with. there are tabs that you can highlight, and the available gallery are being loaded from a php script on another page, but the problem I'm running into is that, first the buttons only toggle after the second click, which is strange and the second problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to make only one button toggle at once, so basically I only want one gallery to be associated at a time, so i don't want multiple ones to be highlighted at the same time. I'm pretty stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using jquery as the JavaScript framework. the functions near the bottom are not completely relevant, but i thought i would include them.

```
   var from_post = false; 
   var addOrRemove = true;

     $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#gallery").load('http://localhost/index.php/site/gallerys_avalible/ #gallerys_avalible', function() {
          $('li').click(function(e) {

            //  console.log($('li').index((this)));


             //  e.preventDefault();

                $(this).toggle(
                function(){
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#CC0000');
                     console.log('backgroudn red');
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#00A8F0'); 
                           console.log('backgroudn blue');
                });


                return false;
              });  

            });

           /* $('li').live('click', function(e) {  

            });
        */
            $('#addNew').click(function () {
                console.log('i got called');
                $('#new_form').fadeIn(1000); 
            });

            $('form').submit(function() {

                if(from_post) {
                    //submit form

                    return true; 

                } else {

                    //dont submit form. 
                    return false; 

                }
            });

        });
```

Thank you to any one who spends the time to help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got waay too many functions going on.

For the second question:

```
document.onLoad(function(){
    $("#gallery").load('http://…');
    $("#gallery > li").toggle(function(){
        function(){$(this).css('background-color', '#CC0000');},
        function(){$(this).css('background-color', 'ORIGINAL_COLOUR');}
    });
});
```

it might be better to add/remove a class instead of applying css. to do this:

```
document.onLoad(function(){
    $("#gallery").load('http://…');
    $("#gallery > li").click(function(){
        $("#gallery > li").toggleClass("active");
        //this will add .active if it's not there, or remove it if it's already there
    });
});
```

This will take care of any click issues as well.

Also, there's the jQuery [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector if you want to select everything else.

Comment: hey thank you so much for your response! I'm still a noob when it comes to jquery.

Comment: np. I amended my answer's first section of code a minute ago (I misread how you were originally trying to do this, but the previous way also works). For no particular reason, I'm a big fan of `not`s.

Comment: Hey i decided to go with one of your old functions, i had to modify it a bit, but it is working great. thank you so much. here is the modified code, for any one who has run into the same issue.                   

$('li').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#CC0000');
        $('li').not($(this)).css('background-color', '#00A8F0');
 
 return false;    
});

the not function or selector is awesome by the way, thanks for telling me about that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using toggle, it doesn't need to be wrapped within a .click binding. It is the event itself.

This code works:

```
$('li').toggle(
function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
},
function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MRNwT/1/

Plus, I don't think toggle is what you want anyway. You want to unhighlight everything, then rehighlight the clicked item.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you simply use [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
 $('li').toggle(function() {         

                function(){
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#CC0000');
                     console.log('backgroudn red');
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#00A8F0'); 
                           console.log('backgroudn blue');
                });
```

Comment: thank you so much for spending the time to answer my question. :) I do have one other question, I was attempting to implement your function, but i kept getting a error that said that the comma after the function was unexceptionable, do you know why that might be?